# How to add breadcrumbs for the aheadworks blog post view

Tags: magento2.4, blog

I have an Aheadworks blog module for Magento 2.

On the blog list page, breadcrumbs are displaying and I want to display breadcrumbs in the blog post view also.

Please suggest any solution.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Hello you have to add `breadcrumbs` using an XML file like:

```
<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs">
  <action method="addCrumb">
    <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">Home</argument>
    <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Home</item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Home</item>
        <item name="link" xsi:type="string">/</item>
    </argument>
  </action>
  <action method="addCrumb">
    <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">Page name</argument>
    <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Page name</item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Page name</item>
        <item name="link" xsi:type="string">Page url </item>
    </argument>
  </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Also, you have to add `breadcrumbs` using PHP `controller` file like:

```
public function execute() {
    $resultPageFactory = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

    // Add breadcrumb
    /** @var \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs */
    $breadcrumbs = $resultPageFactory->getLayout()-> 
    getBlock('breadcrumbs');
    $breadcrumbs->addCrumb('home', [
        'label' => __('Home'),
        'title' => __('Home'),
        'link' => $this->_url->getUrl('')
            ]
    );
    $breadcrumbs->addCrumb('custom_module', [
        'label' => __('Test'),
        'title' => __('Test')
            ]
    );
    return $resultPageFactory;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Bhavin , How to add the dynamic blog post name in above xml. Please suggest.

Comment: @kirankumar, I change the answer you have to check again.